# How to format a float with space between thousands, millions, etc

Tags: python, pandas, format

With :

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,}'.format
```

It displays for number x = 1234567.888 :

```
1,234,567.888
```

What is the appropriate format to show 0 decimals and add a space between thousands, millions, billions, and so on ? Like this

```
1 234 568
```

Comment: Are you looking to round off the digits and then format?

Comment: If I can just format the float to display an integer without rounding it, it is fine. However if I need to round it before, well why not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform this operation you are looking for using python, the following does the trick:

```
from math import trunc
some_float = 1234569.02

print ('{:,}'.format(trunc(some_float)).replace(',', ' '))
```

You can read more about trunc() [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-35-truncate-in-python/).

You can also use '{:,.0f}' to format, as pointed out by @Jon Clements. That does not require importing the math library.

Comment: this does not answer the question of the desired output, just how to remove decimals

Comment: Oh shoot, missed that. Let me add to it.

Comment: @Nivii1406 you don't even need `trunc`... you can use: `'{:,.0f}'` as your format string instead to get rid of any decimals.